# Adding swagger core libraries to my dropwizard application breaks it completely

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, swagger, dropwizard

I have a relatively old dropwizard application with a bunch of outdated dependencies, but it works perfectly fine. We recently decided to generate open API docs from the application and for that we included Swagger libraries.
Everything was working fine locally in intellij. We finished the code and pushed to our deployed machines and there we realize there are some serious problems.
The problem was highlighted when we created the uber jar with maven via:

```
mvn --batch-mode --show-version --update-snapshots --errors '-Dmaven.test.skip=true' clean install
```

Now the uber jar is created just fine. But after running the application, I see the following exception:

```
ERROR [2020-07-08 13:15:34,015] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Unable to start server, shutting down
! org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
! at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
...
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
INFO  [2020-07-08 13:15:34,063] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped application@648f48d3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2020-07-08 13:15:34,077] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped admin@30ce78e3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8002}
WARN  [2020-07-08 13:15:34,083] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder:
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.stop(JpaPersistService.java:115)
! at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.destroy(PersistFilter.java:83)
...
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
INFO  [2020-07-08 13:15:34,087] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@24f70ab3{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
WARN  [2020-07-08 13:15:34,096] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Failure during stop server
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at com.myApp.MyApplication$3.stop(MyAppApplication.java:270)
...
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
! at com.myapp.MyApp.MyAppApplication.main(MyAppApplication.java:105)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
        ...
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
```

And here is the POM file that is working fine. Note that I have removed some irrelevant parts.

```
    <properties>
        <dropwizard.version>1.0.6</dropwizard.version>
        <guice.version>4.1.0</guice.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.193</h2.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1208.jre7</postgresql.version>
        <jsonassert.version>1.3.0</jsonassert.version>
        <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <mail.version>1.4.7</mail.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.8</jackson.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <dropwizard-scala.version>3.0.6</dropwizard-scala.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.21</slf4j-api.version>
        <mockito.version>2.0.2-beta</mockito.version>
        <powermock.version>1.7.3</powermock.version>
        <reflections.version>0.9.10</reflections.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.1</quartz.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.3.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <json.schema.validator.version>2.2.6</json.schema.validator.version>
        <wiremock.version>2.5.0</wiremock.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.6</commons-validator.version>
        <guava-retrying.version>2.0.0</guava-retrying.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluded because of newer dependency in java-jwt -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3-beta</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonassert.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>${reflections.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${json.schema.validator.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rholder</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-retrying</artifactId>
            <version>${guava-retrying.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
            <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
</project>
```

It breaks the application and throws above exception on startup after I added the swagger dependenies on above POM. You will notice that I already tried some exclusions but to no avail.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried listing the dependency tree but there is no clear error showing up. I tried updating different versions but that is going to be ridiculously difficult to resolve. It is something in the POM itself as I tried adding the dependency to a previous commit's POM which does not have the code and it did break it.
I simply have no idea what is wrong here and I am severely stuck with this thing.